# How to set imageview fit to sreen?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have use the android studio and set the image view fit to screen using relative background image i give layout top margin and i set image view fit to screen below part

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:background="@drawable/backgroud">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blacksquare"
    android:alpha=".33"
    />
```

Comment: Set `ScaleType="fitXY"` for `ImageView` and height should be `match_parent`. and `android:layout_marginTop="500dp"` is out of screen may be.If you don't need to apply padding then just remove it.

Comment: Did you follow all what i have said in comment??

Comment: i remove the padding and use the ScaleType="fitXY" then it completely work

Comment: Thats why i told you that did you read my comment properly? BTW its good

Comment: how to write text on this imageview?

Comment: You need to put a TextView over that Imageview for writing the text on Image View. Use FrameLayout as parent for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write the Following ImageView Tag in your Parent Layout.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@drawable/blacksquare"
    />
```

and you can also remove the Paddings from your parent Layout Tag to get fit the Image View in screen without padding..

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for set image in full screen.

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/blacksquare"
android:alpha=".33"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
ScaleType="fitXY"
/>
```